# Simple DB2 Query for connection validation

Tags: sql, db2

I'm looking for a simple DB2 query that can be used to test if a database connection in pool is still valid.  It needs to be a generic query that would execute regardless of which databases exist.

For other database servers, I've used something like 'SELECT 1' or 'SELECT version();'

What would be an equivalent for DB2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try `values 1`.

Also, you can get the current date as

```
VALUES current date
```

or

```
SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

You can also get [the version info as follows](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/03/09/find-the-database-version/)

```
SELECT service_level, fixpack_num, bld_level
FROM TABLE (sysproc.env_get_inst_info()) as A;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Select 1 returns: ILLEGAL SYMBOL "<END-OF-STATEMENT>". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: SQL Code: -104, SQL State: 42601
but adding the (FROM sysibm.sysdummy1) works
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: First let me say that I'm not very familiar with DB2, so I may have boned up the syntax.  I tried "values 1", "SELECT values 1", and "VALUES current date " all of which returned an error.  
Both "SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1" and "SELECT 1 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1" worked well though.
This is all through JDBC using the JCC driver on a zOS based server.