# How to test whether MySQL connection has been timed out by the server (Java)?

Tags: java, mysql, connection-timeout

What is the standard approach in Java to test whether a MySQL connection has been timed out by the server / keep the conneciton alive?  (`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 73.596.145 milliseconds ago` ...)

Some articles recommended periodic pinging to keep the connection alive.  I could start a separated thread which does this, ok.  However, is there some easy test that I could perform and reconnect only if necessary?  Or is periodic pinging the best-performance way to go here?

`boolean java.sql.Connection.isClosed()` states "This method is guaranteed to return true only when it is called after the method Connection.close has been called" and I guess that this will not do the job for me.

I could internally keep track of seconds since last request, compare that to `select @@wait_timeout;` and reconnect if too much time has passed.

So, what is the standard approach to know if the connection has timed out / keep the connection alive?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668506/efficient-sql-test-query-or-validation-query-that-will-work-across-all-or-most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem.

A solution that must be tested is to call the "isValid(int timeout)" method from the java.sql.Connection

Or set autoreconnect in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/auto-reconnect.html

Or change the timeout in mysql (default = 8 hours): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

EDIT: but I think that the best pratice is to open the connection during a transaction and then close it directly after that.