# Why is our Connection Pool Closing?

Tags: java, sql-server, jsf, tomcat, connection-pooling

We have a JSF2.0 webserver running on Apache Tomcat 7.0.54 running on Windows Server 2008 R2. We have 2 SQL servers on on the machine this is running on, and another which hosts our inventory software. One part of our webpage is validation of PartNumbers being added. After reading that Connection Pools are best practice for talking with SQL servers we created one and used it for some of the validation against our inventory software.

Because I wanted a way to be able to check the health of the connection pool I created a test page with a ViewScoped backing bean that validates 2 known good part numbers. Today is the second time this week that the error message "Connection is closed" appeared. Since i'm new to conenction pools and can't seem to find any information regarding this I'm baffled as to what we didn't setup right. I just now reset the Apache server and it is back up and running. So.. to create our connection pool I added some code to the app's META-INF/context.xml.

```
    <Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        name="jdbc/FOODB"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://Foobar\Inventory;databaseName=FooInventory;user=johnDoe;password=astrongpassword;"
    />
```

The basic concept that I have to use the ConnectionPool is that I have an interface called SqlAccessCommand. It is more or less an adapter pattern. In my test page i use the RunUnsafe method so that I can display the error message. So here is the RunUnsafe method.

```
protected static DataSource getDataSource() throws NamingException {
    Context context = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/FOODB");
    return ds;
}
public static <T> T RunUnsafe(SqlAccessCommand<T> command) throws NamingException, SQLException {
    try {
        DataSource ds = getDataSource();
        try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(command.getSqlStatement())) {
            command.prepareStatment(statement);
            try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
                return command.getResults(rs);
            }
        }
    } catch (NamingException | SQLException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(AOSqlInformationHolder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

As you can see i use the try with resources which is supposed to close my connections after use no matter what. Much like the try/catch/finally does, just cleaner (IMO). so when my connection is open this works just fine. so far 2x now I have had to restart the server (since I don't know how to re-open said connection any other way) what am I missing? If more parts of the puzzle are needed leave me a comment and I will post what I can. Thank you.

**EDIT**

just looked into the log files and this morning there was this exception thrown

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

According to the comments thus far it was assumed a timeout. Does this error message still point in that direction?

Comment: The connection(s) are probably timing out after inactivity.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch isn't that only if i don't close my connection? and if so, isn't that what try with resources is for?

Comment: The connections aren't `close`(d) when you use a pool; they go back to the pool. Eventually (if the connection is unused long enough), the database assumes that connection is bad and closes it. You'll need to look into your pool configuration options for solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add some options <sup>**1**</sup> in the connection pool configuration to detect if the connection is still valid.

The simplest way is to run a simple SQL statement <sup>**2**</sup> to test the connection.

So the pool configuration can be:

```xml
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          name="jdbc/FOODB"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
          url="jdbc:sqlserver://Foobar\Inventory;databaseName=FooInventory;user=johnDoe;password=astrongpassword;"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          validationQueryTimeout="1000"
          testOnBorrow="true"
/>
```

---

*Notes*

1. To view the available options: [*The Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)
2. *[Efficient SQL test query or validation query that will work across all (or most) databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668506/efficient-sql-test-query-or-validation-query-that-will-work-across-all-or-most)*

Comment: Thank you for finding this list of options. I was going to go with the abandoned removal thing that is in the same document, but this seems more logical.

Comment: Mod up because this answer actually has a solution.

Comment: I think it should be noted that this solution incurs the cost of validating the `Connection` on every query. There is (sadly) no magic bullet.

Comment: With this solution, the statement is executed only to get a connection from the pool. e.g. `Connection conn = datasource.getConnection();`. Maybe you want to see the options on the link provided in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your connections are almost certainly timing out due to inactivity, based on your log message of *com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error* you could read this [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957018.aspx) note which says,

> A connection was forcibly closed by a peer. This normally results from a loss of the connection on the remote socket due to a timeout or a restart.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Abandon configurations options.

```
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    name="jdbc/FOODB"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://Foobar\Inventory;databaseName=FooInventory;user=johnDoe;password=astrongpassword;"
    removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
        logAbandoned="true" 
/>
```

Comment: `removeAbandoned` can be useful when the **application** does not close the connection properly. However, the problem of OP is that the connections are closed by the **database**.