# DB Does Not Reconnect After Connection Drop

Tags: spring, oracle11g, spring-data, hikaricp

I have an application using SpringData, HikariCP and Oracle 11. When the connection to the DB drops and comes back the application is unable to communicate with the DB unless the application is restarted. I tried adding the following properties as some suggested on similar questions but they did not solve the problem.

```
spring.datasource.remove-abandoned=true
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These properties are NOT for hikaricp. so they are not in effect.

Refer [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby) for the supported properties.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle  i think `SELECT 1` isn't the [appropriate Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668506/efficient-sql-test-query-or-validation-query-that-will-work-across-all-or-most#answer-3670000).

Can you try :

```
SELECT 1 FROM any_existing_table WHERE 1=0
```

Comment: These properties are NOT for hikaricp. so they are not in effect.

Refer HikariCP for the supported properties.

Comment: @Nitin You were absolutely right, using the spring boot properties resulted in HikariCP not being configured or used. I changed the config to one of the recommended versions and all was well. Would you like writing an answer?

Comment: @SamanthaCatania Hi, can you please paste / show the config that worked for you ? I am not sure which spring data source properties affect the HikariCP not being configured properly. It would be really helpful. Thanks.