# Springboot 2.0 - disable reconnecting to database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

After switching from spring-boot 1.5.x to spring-boot-2.x, when db connection is down, my spring application tries to reconnect to database constantly. I cannot even call a health check endpoint.

This only occurs in spring-boot-2.x

It might try to reconnect but, in my case, it should not block the whole application.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb?ssl=false
    username: dbuser
    password: dbpass
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I get the flood of the following error, when the db is down.

**Error**

```
2018-05-31 14:15:42.399 ERROR 90850 --- [onnection adder] org.postgresql.Driver                    : Connection error: 

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:245) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:697) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:683) [HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:69) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:156) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you waited long enough? In my case when the DB is down /actuator/health takes around 25 seconds because the health check itself tries to connect to the database.

Comment: As you can see in the stacktrace it's HikariPool's behavior, which became a default connection pool since Spring 2.0 release. Try research on that. Look for some properties.

Comment: Does it make sense for your app to be up without a DB?

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov yes, I noticed it but I could not find a proper configuration or any explanation to disable the behavior or reduce the timeout value if there is at all.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes, after waiting for a certain time, it returns back to normal behavior. Now it's solved for me, I reduced the timeout value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on my comment, try these properties:

```
# Values in MS
spring
    datasource:
        hikari:
          connection-timeout: 60000
          validation-timeout: 60000
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding these 2 properties in your configuration file:

```
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

Comment: Given that Hikari is the standard connection pool in Spring Boot 2, your suggestion should have no effect or even makes things worse.
First, Hikari [always validates connections](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Bad-Behavior:-Handling-Database-Down) before handing them out.
Second, a JDBC-4-compliant driver allows to validate the connection without having to set a validation query. Defining such a query anyway [is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270023/193705).